# LINQ average for pairs

Tags: linq

A LINQ challenge:

I have a ordered list of numbers. assume { 2 , 3 , 5, 7, 11 }

I like to calculate the average between each item and the next.
Is there any short way to do this with linq?

so the result in this case should be :
 { 2.5 , 4, 6, 9 }

Comment: possible duplicate of [LINQ to calculate a moving average of a SortedList<dateTime,double>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166716/linq-to-calculate-a-moving-average-of-a-sortedlistdatetime-double)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Enumerable.Zip`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd267698%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
List<int> ints = new List<int> {  2, 3, 5, 7, 11  };
IEnumerable<double> averages = ints.Zip(ints.Skip(1), (i1, i2) => (i1 + i2) / 2d);
```

This zips the list with itself (starting with the second element due to `Skip(1)`).

The result: `2.5 , 4.0, 6.0, 9.0`